# Ion-datetime - calendar view blank - white text on white background - android / web

Tags: ionic-framework

When I open the ion-datetime in calendar mode it is blank on Android 8.
Some users also get this in chrome on PC.
It seems fine on ios in either light or dark mode.

It seems the color of the day numbers is white on a white background.

[image]

Code:

```
 <ion-col *ngIf="startDateType === 'future'" class="date-start-container">
            <ion-datetime-button color="dark" datetime="dateControlStart"></ion-datetime-button>
  
            <ion-modal [isOpen]="isStartDateModalOpen" [keepContentsMounted]="true">
              <ng-template>
                <ion-datetime id="dateControlStart" class="shadow-override" #dateControlStart
                  [value]="dateStartString"
                  presentation="date"
                  [showDefaultTitle]="true"
                  [showDefaultButtons]="true"
                  [min]="dateStartString"
                  [max]="dateFutureString"
                  (ionChange)="onDateStartChange($event)" 
                >
                  <span slot="title">Select a membership/pass start date</span>
                </ion-datetime>
              </ng-template>
            </ion-modal>
          </ion-col>
```

Partial fix:
I managed to get it partially fixed using this but it only works if you close and then reopen the ion-datetime.

```
ion-datetime {

  &:not(.datetime-placeholder) {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Update:
The color is set to currentcolor in the css.
[image: css]

Comment: Are there any errors in console?

If not, I think some css (maybe in global css) must be affecting your calendar.

Have you tried to inspect the element with devtools and check css property that is setting the color to the numbers?

Comment: @Miguel the color is "color: currentcolor;" I will do some more testing with a fresh project

Comment: no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I have found what is causing the issue.
I was using *ngIf in the containing element.

I have replaced

```
<ion-col *ngIf="startDateType === 'future'" class="date-start-container">
```

with

```
<ion-col class="date-start-container" [ngClass]="{'hide-me': startDateType !== 'future'}">
            <ion-datetime-button color="dark" datetime="dateControlStart"></ion-datetime-button>
  
            <ion-modal [isOpen]="isStartDateModalOpen" [keepContentsMounted]="true">
              <ng-template>
                <ion-datetime [ngClass]="{'ion-datetime-fix': applyIonDateTimeFix}"
...

async ngOnInit() {
 setTimeout(() => {
      this.applyIonDateTimeFix = true;
    }, 5000);
}

.ion-datetime-fix {
  color: black!important;
}

.hide-me {
  display: none!important;
}
```